# Input box limit in VB

Tags: vb.net, user-input, inputbox

a simple question: can I set the limit for an input through an input box in vb?

When the user inserts a string larger than the database corresponding field, that's a problem obviously.

Like the textBoxes have a MaxLength, is there a way to set a similar restriction to an inputBox?

Thanks

Comment: The InputBox is a leftover from VB6 days. It is very limited in functionality. I suggest to develop your own class and reuse it. Not very difficult.

Comment: @Steve: beat me to it.

Comment: Google for `custom inputbox vb.net`, should get plenty of results, such as [this one](http://vbnetworld.blogspot.ca/2011/04/create-your-own-custom-inputbox.html).

Comment: Thank you, I know it's very limited and also where it comes from. I know how to achieve what I want but I was just asking if the input box had such feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little easier than creating a custom class...

Instead why not create a temporary string variable and assign it by your input box. . .

then check the count in a do until loop...

EX.

```
 Dim str As String = InputBox("Name", [Title]:="name", [XPos]:=50, [YPos]:=50)

    Do Until str.Count() > 0 And str.Count() < 8

        MessageBox.Show("I am sorry but you need to input between 1 and 7 characters")

        str = InputBox("Name", [Title]:="name", [XPos]:=50, [YPos]:=50)

    Loop
```