# how can i limit inputbox to 11 numerical values in vb

Tags: vb.net, inputbox

How can I limit an inputbox to 11 numerical values in vb? I would like to enable a person to edit a phone number but seem to be having issue with my current code.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each x As ListViewItem In lvCustomers.Items
        Dim contactEdit As String
        If x.Checked Then
            contactEdit = CInt(InputBox("Modify contact no."))
            Do Until contactEdit.Count = 11
                MessageBox.Show("Maximum numerical digits of 11")
            Loop

            x.SubItems(5).Text = contactEdit

            x.Checked = False

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686928/input-box-limit-in-vb

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regex to check this:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
'[...]
Dim isValid As Boolean = Regex.Match("12345", "^\d{0,11}$").Success()
```

Your code can look like this:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
'[...]
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each x As ListViewItem In lvCustomers.Items
        Dim contactEdit As String

        If x.Checked Then
            contactEdit = InputBox("Modify contact no.")

            Do Until Regex.Match(contactEdit, "^\d{0,11}$").Success()
                MessageBox.Show("Maximum numerical digits of 11")
                contactEdit = InputBox("Modify contact no.")
            Loop

            x.SubItems(5).Text = contactEdit
            x.Checked = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You can define the minimum and maximum length of the input on the RegExp (`{minValue,maxValue}`). The input have to be numeric (`\d`). You can find a explanation of the used RegExp on this site: https://regex101.com/r/6h7z2u/1

**Hint:** I recommend to remove the `CInt` from `InputBox` because the code throws an `Exception` if the value from `InputBox` isn't a valid Integer. With the used RegExp of the solution, only numbers can written to the `InputBox`.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I have declared Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions at the top of my page. The section in your code 'regularexpressions' is underline and says its not declared. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are using the `Import` you have to remove the `RegularExpressions.` in front of the `Regex`. From `RegularExpressions.Regex` to `Regex`. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use **Len(contactEdit.Text) = 11** Instead of **contactEdit.Count = 11**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each x As ListViewItem In lvCustomers.Items
        Dim contactEdit As String
        If x.Checked Then
            contactEdit = CInt(InputBox("Modify contact no."))
            Do Until Len(contactEdit.Text) >= 11
                MessageBox.Show("Maximum numerical digits of 11")
            Loop
            x.SubItems(5).Text = contactEdit
            x.Checked = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```